# What is the name of this pink flower wirh spatulate shape leaves and bulb root?

Tags: identification, flowers, leaves

Dark green Spatulate entire leaves, 5 petals light pink and darkening to deep pink at the edges. The petals fan outward.

[image]

My cousin bought the bulb and had no idea what it would look like until it flowered. She still has no idea. It's a beautiful flower. The leaves look hardy. I'd like to know the name, variety and origin.

Answer (score 2):

It's Adenium obesum, common name Desert Rose, image below

https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Adenium_obesum_(3).jpg

It's a tropical plant classed as a succulent; it prefers temperatures in the range of 75-95 deg F. Flowers best in good light, doesn't do well in shady conditions, needs regular watering during the growing/flowering season, but should never be allowed to get too wet or waterlogged.  More care info below

http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ep474

Native to south Sahara, parts of Africa and Arabia, but grown in many places round the world as houseplants.